# Unity Web Player distorts objects

Tags: firefox, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I'm making a 2D isometric game with Unity and I made a build for the Unity Web Player and tested it on my browser (Safari 9.0.3 on Mac os El Capitan 10.11.3) without any major issues.

It also was tested on a windows 10 Pro version 1511 computer (on the Internet Explorer, Version 11.212.10586.0, and Firefox, Version 45.0.2) and the game is completely unplayable. The game objects are distorted as the camera moves. Please check this video to see the bug in question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NG8B1agFsY

I know this question goes a little off-topic but I just wanted to ask if someone else has seen this bug, and if so, how it was solved.

If you want more information to find out why this happens, I'll post it here.

Thank you very much!

Observation: No errors were raised while testing the game on the Unity Editor.

Edit 1: The Windows computer was a HP ProBook 4530s (LH315EA) and the Mac was a Macbook Pro Early 2011.

Comment: Are you running the windows 10 on bootcamp with Apple hardware?

Comment: No. It was tested on a different computer. An HP ProBook 4530s (LH315EA). The Mac is an Early 2011 Macbook Pro.

Comment: What Os did the An HP ProBook 4530s   originally come with and what year?

Comment: The original OS was Windows 7 on 2012. The OS was changed as soon as Windows 10 was released.

Comment: That is a driver or graphic card issue. Try the stuff from my answer. Maybe, one of them will work for you. Also, to reply to someone in your question, always use the @Name so that SO will notify the person. If you don't, they wont know you replied to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has **nothing** to do with Unity. The problem is either **graphic** driver or your **Onboard GPU card**. I searched to see if there is a **Windows 10** driver available for your computer but there weren't.

Not sure if there is a fix since there is **no** official Win10 driver but you can try [here](http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/hp/laptops-desktops/hp-probook-4530s/189) and install HP Driver Utility. It will show you outdated Driver and you should update it if is a graphic driver.

If that doesn't work, go to the [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu) website, click on **Download now** and it will an app and automatically scan for your latest driver.

Problem still there? Go to **Device Manager**, select **Display Adapters**->select the name of your graphic card. Righ-click the choose **Properties**, go to the **Driver** *tab* the click on **Update Driver**. Click **Search automatically for updated driver software**. Windows will look on the internet for the latest driver and will update if there is one.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the Windows computer in my possession now but tomorrow I will try to go through the steps you suggested. Many thanks for your help sir :)

Comment: I ran your answer on my Windows and it didn't work on Firefox :/ The good news is that it was fixed on the Internet Explorer :D Do you have any more ideas why it might not work on Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: @Dayman75 The reason it might not work on Firefox is because the web developers on that website are too lazy to support Firefox or maybe they used a feature only available on Internet Exploerer. Which one of my answers worked for ? If any of them worked, you can go ahead and accept this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you :) The Internet Explorer was fixed and I could continue my work :D